# How to set user and save it with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

Is it possible to define a user model only once and then use it to update the data ? In all the examples I found the update is in the `findOne` callback. Is it possible to do something like :

```
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function (io) {
    'use strict';
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var user = User.findOne({
            '_id': socket.request.session.passport.user._id
        });

        socket.on('save_data', function (data) {
            user.update({'data': data});
        });

        socket.on('remove_data', function () {
            user.update({'data': false});
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are "a lot" of very bad examples that suggest using `.findOne()` and then modifying the content retured and using `.save()` to commit back to the database.

What you really "should" be doing is this:

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('save_data', function (data) {
            user.update(
               { "_id": socket.request.session.passport.user._id  },
               { "$set": { "data": data } },
               function(err,result) {
                  // react to result in callback
               }
           );
        });

        socket.on('remove_data', function () {
            user.update(
               { "_id": socket.request.session.passport.user._id  },
               { "$unset": { "data": "" } },
               function(err,result) {
                  // react to result in callback
               }
           );
        });
    });
```

Where both [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) are acting on the "data" property of your document.

These operations are "atomic", and will update the document according to "the current state it was when the modification was made".

Any `.findOne()` and `.save()` examples are **not**, unless you add aditional handling with "version" consideration. Even then, you are likely to run into problems.

So it is best to use the "native" update operators of MongoDB to alter the document properties and content, as they are designed with consideration to acting on the properties ( and **only** the properties ) you specify in your update statement.

Of course that is just "updating" properties on an existing document by either "setting" them or removing them.

If your "documents" do not even actually exist then you can modify that to:

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('save_data', function (data) {
            user.update(
               { "_id": socket.request.session.passport.user._id  },
               { "$set": { "data": data } },
               { "upsert": true },
               function(err,result) {
                  // react to result in callback
               }
           );
        });

        socket.on('remove_data', function () {
            user.remove(
               { "_id": socket.request.session.passport.user._id  },
               function(err,result) {
                  // react to result in callback
               }
           );
        });
    });
```

Where the first `.update()` call uses the ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) modifier which "creates" a new document where one does not yet exist. Anything in a `$set` operation is also added to the document, or where the document exists it is "updated". Typical for session storage, though you could optimize this, but that's another question.

In the reverse case the [`.remove()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) method acutally "deletes" the whole document from the collection rather than simply "removing a property" which was what was done previously.

So depending on what your case actually is, this is the better approach to multiple transactions against the database that could have other operations occuring "in between" your "fetch" and other operations.